# Task 'browser-sync' is not in your gulpfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, gulp, browser-sync

I just started to use browsersync. So I started learning about gulp.
I installed gulp using `npm install gulp -g` command. After this I initialized my project directory with `package.json` file by following command `npm init`. I then installed gulp in my project directory by `npm install gulp --save-dev` command.I also installed browsersync by `npm install browser-sync --save-dev` command.

Now I tried to run browsersync using gulp by `gulp browser-sync` command which gives me an error **Task 'browser-sync' is not in your gulpfile**

Below is my gulpfiles.js file

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// process JS files and return the stream.
gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp.src('js/*js')
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// create a task that ensures the `js` task is complete before
// reloading browsers
gulp.task('js-watch', ['js'], function (done) {
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
});

// use default task to launch Browsersync and watch JS files
gulp.task('serve', ['js'], function () {

// Serve files from the root of this project
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "./"
    }
});

// add browserSync.reload to the tasks array to make
// all browsers reload after tasks are complete.
  gulp.watch("js/*.js", ['js-watch']);
});
```

I had already tried including `module.exports = gulp;` line at beginning as well as at end of gulpfile.js but the error persist. My current gulp version is 3.9.1 on mac OSX 10.12.3

Please help I am stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you called your task `serve` and not `browserSync`:

```
// use default task to launch Browsersync and watch JS files
// NOTE how this task is called serve:
gulp.task('serve', ['js'], function () {

// Serve files from the root of this project
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "./"
    }
});
```

You could just change its' name:

```
// use default task to launch Browsersync and watch JS files
// NOTE at the name of the task now
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['js'], function () {

// Serve files from the root of this project
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: "./"
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a doubt. there are multiple tasks with different names but why you have chosen this one. by the way the example is from browsersync documentation.

Comment: I chose that task because it is the one in which you initialize your browsersync server.
Have you tried running `gulp serve` with your current code and see if browserSync works properly?

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)